# Optical drive keeps ejecting automatically

Tags: cd, drive, optical

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS a few days ago and after 2 days, my drive started ejecting itself after some time, without my issuing any command.

It's not a hardware problem because I ran the BIOS for like half an hour. The drive works fine on Windows 10 (I'm dual-booting)

I have a hunch that it keeps asking for media to insert, but don't know why. (I installed Ubuntu from a USB).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Run This Command in terminal.

```
eject -i 1
```

Comment: What does this do? I read in the help "manual eject protection", but what is that?